# Trivial jQuery event isn't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This is a very strange problem, and I'm sure that it has a very simple solution, but I've been staring at this for a while now and can't seem to figure it out. All I'm trying to do is have a simple alert pop up when a radio button is changed between 'Yes' and 'No' on my rails app.
The source snippet of the radio buttons I'm trying to select looks like this:

```
<input id="line_item_is_imprintable_yes" name="line_item_is_imprintable" type="radio" value="yes" /><label for="is_imprintable_yes">Yes</label>
<input id="line_item_is_imprintable_no" name="line_item_is_imprintable" type="radio" value="no" /><label for="is_imprintable_no">No</label>
```

My coffeescript file looks like this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('input:radio[name="line_item_is_imprintable"]').change ->
    alert('change!')
```

When I try to recreate it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ9HP/) it works, which throwing me for a loop. Any insights? Thank you!

Comment: Are you adding these fields dynamically?

Comment: eventually yes, but for now no. I've tried using
`$(document).on('change' ... )` which also works in the fiddle and not in my app.

Comment: rails 4 yes, turbolinks no

Answer (score 0):

i'd use class:

```
<input id="line_item_is_imprintable_yes" name="line_item_is_imprintable" class="line_item_is_imprintable" type="radio" value="yes" /><label for="is_imprintable_yes">Yes</label>
<input id="line_item_is_imprintable_no" name="line_item_is_imprintable" class="line_item_is_imprintable" type="radio" value="no" /><label for="is_imprintable_no">No</label>
```

then use:

```
$("input.line_item_is_imprintable").change(function (){
    alert('change!');
});
```

alternatively, throw a div around the inputs e.g.

```
<div id="line_item_is_imprintable">
    <input id="line_item_is_imprintable_yes" name="line_item_is_imprintable" type="radio" value="yes" /><label for="is_imprintable_yes">Yes</label>
    <input id="line_item_is_imprintable_no" name="line_item_is_imprintable" value="no" /><label for="is_imprintable_no">No</label>
</div>
```

then go:

```
$("div#line_item_is_imprintable").find("input:radio").change(function (){
    alert('change!');
});
```

just makes it easier to read...